# Adding a callback for processing the UART data seems to cause issues with I2C interrupts

Tags: stm32, i2c, embedded, uart

So I wrote peripheral drivers on STM32 and wrote a simple application to read the user input via terminal and respond accordingly. I am using interrupts for both UART and I2C but the way I previously did was more towards "polling" than just interrupts, as shown in the example below.

```
// uart.c
void UART_session(USART_Handle *usart, I2C_Handle *i2c) {
    char tempBuffer[usart->rxSize];
    memset(tempBuffer, 0, rxBufferSize);
    while(true)
    {
        ReceiveSerialData(usart);
        ParseSerialData(usart, tempBuffer);
        bool status = ReadTemp(usart, tempBuffer, I2C_Handle);
        WriteUart(usart, tempBuffer); 
    }
}
// main.c
int main(void) {

    HAL_init();
    I2C_init();
    UART_init();

    UART_session();  // loop
    while (true);
}
```

But I modified the code to call a callback function after i'm done receiving the data (using `\r` as an indication) for processing the data, executing it accordingly, and continue what it was doing before... **but when I do so, I don't receive I2C interrupts anymore.** I also made sure the static `i2cHandle` does have the same address as the original `i2c` from `main`.

````
// uart_hal.c 
void USART2_IRQHandler(void)
{
   // ....
    if (ptrUSARTx->pUSARTx->SR & USART_SR_TC) // transmission complete
    {
        if (ptrUSARTx->USART_State == USART_TX_BUSY)
        {
            if (!ptrUSARTx->txLength)        // no more bytes to send
            {
                USART_DisableTransmission();
            }
        }
        else if (ptrUSARTx->USART_State == USART_RX_BUSY)
        {
            if (!ptrUSARTx->rxLength || endLine)        // no more bytes to receive OR user pressed enter
            {
                USART_DisableTransmission();
                USART_AppCallback(pUSART); // ** ADDED THIS CALLBACK **
            }
        }
    }
}

// uart.c
void USART_AppCallback(USART_Handle_t *usart) {
        ParseSerialData(usart, tempBuffer);
        bool status = ReadTemp(usart, tempBuffer, i2cHandle); // ** NO I2C INTERRUPTS **
}

static I2C_Handle_t *i2cHandle;
void USART_receive(USART_Handle_t *usart, I2C_Handle_t *i2c)
{
    i2cHandle = i2c;
    USART_EnableInterrupts(USART_RX_BUSY);
}

// main.c
int main(void) {

    HAL_init();
    I2C_init();
    USART_init();

    USART_receive(&usart, &i2c);  
    while (true);
}```
````

Comment: This looks a bit confused. ISRs need to do as little as possible, they should **never** try to call major chunks of application code and especially not ones which then use other peripherals in a non-trivial way, enter loops, or wait.  Really there's no reason to be enabling and disabling your UART and interrupts, just leave it running and handle the foreground vs. ISR interchange with appropriately managed circular buffers.  You may find it's easier to do everything but the UART receive in the foreground anyway (ie, busy-wait on the UART transmit and the I2C presuming you are the I2C master).

Comment: I don't think the callback is doing some significant amount of work here. The idea that I had in mind was to have interrupts enabled, have ISR fire for each byte received, and process them for each set of data bytes I get (till `\r`), and then repeat. I thought about using circular buffers but i want to do step by step; just making a small change is causing me enough trouble but yeah I do plan on using it only after I figure this issue out. And i'm not sure if I fully followed you..

Comment: Well, you don't think it does, but it does.

Comment: Specifically you are trying to do an I2C operation from within the UART ISR.  That you hid it from yourself in an application callback means nothing to the processor.  Don't do that.  Parse your UART data in the foreground, and if you find something that implies you should do an I2C operation then start that from the foreground, too.  Step by step construction isn't a bad idea, but the problem is that you've taken a step down a path that leads to only trouble.  Your UART ISR should basically just be a larger software FIFO around the tiny hardware one to give your code time to catch up.

Comment: by foreground, I guess you mean the application and not ISR, yeah? like I said in the description, I had the working code where I was parsing the UART data in the application,  and doing I2C read but for that, I was explicitly calling a function to do so, which didn't seem the correct usage of interrupts to me. I'd imagine it work something like, you have your application running, and everytime you receive a byte from uart, ISR is triggered, and once you know enough data is received to be parsed, your application gets interrupted which parses, and does I2C read, and you continue where u left..

Comment: You got the first half right, but then the second a bit off.  Parsing wouldn't typically be triggered by an interrupt, but rather by the foreground application finding something of interest in the FIFO that the ISR is using to pass data to it.

Comment: but how is foreground application 'keeping track' track of the FIFO? is it continually checking it? maybe i'm still trying to get the 'flow'; is ISR passing anything to the application? If not, the only way I see it will work is how I demonstrated in in`UART_session ()`; the ISR returns when it receives `\r` from the user, and then in `UART_session()`, you parse it and do I2C operation without having to worry since you're no longer in the UART ISR. (but i'm trying to use a different approach). And if ISR calls the application, one way I see it working is to set I2C IRQ's priority higher

Comment: In the simplest form the ISR shouldn't pay any attention to the data, just put it in the fifo as it must return *immediately* regardless of the data.  The main loop polls the fifo any time it conveniently can and pulls characters out, either putting them in a line buffer or parsing them character by character in a state machine.

Comment: right. a couple of follow-ups: 1) just to clarify, do we have USART interrupt enabled at all times so it continues to store the data into the buffer and when we need the data, we call `UART_session()` which pops off the FIFO, which we then process it as opposed to enabling it every time we call `UART_session()` and disable upon returning from ISR? I think the former makes sense since we are not stopping the data from being stored into our buffer, but is it generally okay to have peripheral interrupts enabled like that in your application?

Comment: 2) by line buffer, did you mean to store a set of bytes before `\r`?

Answer (score 1):

The callback runs in the context of UART interrupt.

Therefore it blocks further UART interrupts, and all other lower priority interrupts, until the callback returns so the UART interrupt exits and normal program flow and other interrupts can continue. You can't even receive and buffer further UART characters for the next line during a lengthy operation.

This is exactly the thing almost all embedded programming tutorials warn about, do not do anything in an interrupt you don't have to do, especially don't do lengthy and complex operations, like UART parsing or executing arbitrary operations from there.

Comment: right, so all subsequent interrupts would be blocked until after ISR is done being executed. This leads me to a question: what are callbacks used for in ISRs? if i don't have a callback, how do I make use of interrupts such that I only get interrupts for handling a specific set of bytes received over uart, and then once done, continue what was previously being done? also, is uart parsing considered something complex?

Comment: First of all, not the parsing itself is complex, but imagine you have a command you type in and that takes long to execute, like blink_led_for_10_seconds(), or even worse, command that needs interrupts to work, it won't be able to do anything useful unless you rearrange interrupt priorities so that timer and I2C interrupts get executed even during UART. The callback is just a model how to separate driver code from the application that uses the driver. Instead of callback you could just directly set a flag that X happened, or with the callback, let application set a flag that X happened.

Comment: yeah like in my case, if I need to set up, say, I2C peripheral interrupt within an uart's ISR, I would have to increase the i2c's interrupt priority to more than that of uart for it work, yes? i still couldn't think of a way to get what I want without a callback, cause assuming the program is stuck in main's while loop, and then each for byte received over uart, ISR is triggered which populates the rx buffer until certain point when you want to process it, which is when I need an indication as to "okay, data is ready to be processed" without me having to explicitly call any function

Comment: Uh, but calling the callback is an explicit call of function. And if your main while loop is stuck, then fix that so it isn't stuck, why it would be stuck anyway? Of course you can trigger/start an I2C operation to initiate from the UART callback, which waits for almost nothing and takes almost no time to return. But you can't wait for I2C completion in the UART interrupt.

Comment: okay about main while loop being stuck, I mean the application is doing something. ideally instead of a loop, i would be doing something else. So you're saying I should make I2C read operation nonblocking if I were to use inside UART ISR? how would a nonblocking I2C read function look like? cause right now, it transmits the address bytes, and then reads the data off that address, and returns the processed bytes

Comment: You really shouldn't try to do anything with I2C from within the UART ISR... it makes no sense to do so, and even if it did, it would require a lot more awareness to make it safe than yet being demonstrated.  Just have your parser running as part of the application in the foreground trigger a *blocking* I2C operation so you can keep things simple and unconfused.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - I understand, and I do have this code working as I demonstrated in the snippet using `UART_session()`, but I just feel it's not the right way of using interrupts since I'd have to specifically call this function to be able to read uart data rather than getting interrupted from your main function when either a byte is received or when the user has entered `\r` which is why I had a callback

Comment: It sounds like that is the central conceptual mistake.  In fact, your main loop should precisely be *polling* a software buffer or flag to see if the UART ISR has yet collected anything it can act on.  Effectively the role of the ISR is to catch data as it comes in, and the role of the main loop is to act on the data when it is convenient to do so, *not* exactly when it comes in, but rather when whatever else that was in process is completed or at a point where a new operation can be done based on the received message.

Comment: It's probably helpful to think about what would happen if you did not have an ISR but simply polled the UART directly.  Not infrequently, that actually *can* work.  The risk is that if your main loop spends a little too long completing actions triggered by the processing of a message, it might not start watching the UART again in time to catch the first characters of the next message.  So you put the ISR in there to grab and save characters before they get lost.  But the main loop continues to poll - it just polls the buffer the ISR is filling, rather than the UART itself.

Comment: ah, I see. so `UART_session()` is correctly implemented except maybe I would need to get rid of the while loop. So the flow would look more like: `main` calls `UART_session()` whenever there's a need to, which in turn reads the FIFO, processes it, and does I2C operation which is independent of what ISR does i.e writes to the FIFO. So having interrupts doesn't result in any *loss* of data as opposed to polling since it'd halt an application. So technically i'm still *polling* the function in my application but I'd just need to be careful with the read/write indexes of the FIFO I guess, yes?

Comment: Yes, the indicies need to be declared volatile and you need to handle foreground access to them as a critical section, ie, with interrupts disabled.

Comment: also, then I don't need any callback at all right

Comment: um, do interrupts really need to be disabled if i'm using a FIFO with indices? i thought FIFO does allow the reading of new data while the old one is being processed? so the read index is updated by the application while write index by the ISR and read index can only go until write index (indicating all the bytes in the FIFO are read/processed)

Comment: To actually implement the sink side of a software FIFO typically requires a `critical section` ie a very small chunk of code during which interrupts are disabled.  There are with extreme care ways to avoid that, but you have to have a very solid idea of what sorts of operations are atomic on your processor.